# Huge amount of noise appeared in the kalman filter

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I am implementing a Kalman filter but I am getting a huge amount of noise to the result. The amount of noise which I added and code for it is:

```
y = np.arange(100)
y = y + 0.0065 * np.random.randn() # yaw rate
```

My resulting output is:

[image]

0.0065 is already very much less noise. Is there any way to clean this noise?

Comment: Have you tried a low-pass filter?

Comment: @joostblack thank you for your reply. No, I have not tried because I want to use the Kalman filter for the problem. Could you please explain a bit more about using a low pass filter for this problem?

Comment: A low pass filter lets the low frequencies through, and filters out the high frequencies. This is often used for noise removal in signals.You can see that the gitter in your image has a higher frequency than your signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kalman filter is indeed one way to filter noise out of your observations. If well implemented and tuned to the dynamics of your problem, it can effectively retrieve accurate estimates considering a Gaussian noise scenario (for different noise models the classical Kalman filter may not be suitable). As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), you need to tune your process and observation covariance noise matrices. Sometimes its a process of trial and error. The more noisy you consider your observations to be, the more weight the filter puts into the previous knowledge. The more noisy you consider your process to be (highly dynamic), the less weight the filter puts into the previous knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Does it mean that the more noise the system has, the more kalaman filter accuracy will be and vice versa? please comment on this confusion as well. Thanks!

Comment: @jaz no, by all means. The more noisy your observations are, the less accurate your estimates will be. This is true for any filter. The first step on any estimation is always to try (if possible) to improve the quality of your observations.

Comment: @jaz What I was trying to highlight, was the intuition behind the Kalman filter. The more noisy you think your observations are (less reliable), the less the Kalman filter 'believes' in them, and therefore the more it 'believes' on the prediction of the current state (position, attitude, etc.) based on the previous state and the current dynamics. Its always a weighted ponderation between new observations and what you expected be based on the previous information.